# Центрирование всей страницы при масштабировании

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, недавно заметил, что при масштабировании страницы, весь документ остаётся слева, а вот например в вк всё остаётся посередине. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: добавляйте ссылку или еще как-то надо продемонстрировать пробему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов куча... Но один из лучших `FLEX`

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class=parent>
  <div class=child></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы центрировать что-то, надо задать `display: block;` и `margin: auto;`. У элементов div и так по дефолту стоит block; поэтому остается ограничить ширину и дать авто-маргин (маргин задает свободное поле снаружи элемента). Дополнительное ограничение пикселями, чтобы у совсем широких экранов не получился километровый блок.

```
<style> .content {width: 80%; max-width: 1200px; margin: auto;} </style>

<div class="content"></div>
```

[ДЕМО](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/4bz0gw6s/) (сдвигайте там рамку) [можно и минимальную ширину ограничить: `min-width: 600px;`]

Точно также можно и картинки центрировать...

```
<img src="..." style="margin: auto; display: block;">
```

Comment: ну вот примерно я догадываюсь о чём , открой youtube и попробуй колёсиком уменьши масштаб ...

Answer (score 0):

Обернуть всё содержимое в блок требуемой ширины, который отцентрировать с помощью, например, свойства `margin: auto`